# VSTS: Group level between feature and work item

Tags: azure-devops

I am working as a Product Owner for a development team using scrum, we are using VSTS for our backlog.

So far I have been organizing my backlog using Epics and Features, I am mainly using features.

I use Features both to group work items but also for keeping control of delivering stuff. If I for instance know that I need to deliver a certain functionality a certain day then I create a Feature for that and include the needed work items. I need to do that because I manage many projects simultaneously.

So far, so good.

But now Product Management want to start creating Epics and Features for them to organize work. I can live without the Epics, and it is fine that they create the features and I add work items. But when I start executing I need some way to organize into deliverables.

Any idea how I can do that, basically I need a group like features but in between feature and work item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add tags for your and other Epics to distinguish them...

> basically I need a group like features but in between feature and work item

Alternatively you can create a new work item type like `features`. Please see [Customize a project using an inherited process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav) for details.

> 1. Create an inherited process
> 2. Custom the process
> 3. [Add a new work item type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav#add-or-modify-work-item-types)
> 4. ...
> 5. [Apply the customized process to your project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav#apply-the-customized-process-to-your-project)

---

**UPDATE:**

You need to add a new `Portfolio backlog` level, but in Azure DevOps (VSTS) the new Portfolio backlogs **can only be added as the top level**, that means the hierarchy should be  `Deliverable  > Epic > Feature > Backlog Item`.

So, in this case you can rename them to match your requirements, for example  rename `Feature to Deliverable`,   `Epic  to Feature`, `Deliverable  to Epic`...

Please see [Customize your backlogs or boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-backlogs-boards?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav) for details.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your alternative idea is what I want. I create a new work item type. Lets call it "Deliverable". Now I just want to add it to the hierachy like this:

Epic
 > Feature
   > Deliverable
     > Backlog Item


How do I do that?

Comment: @Claus You need to add a new `Portfolio backlog`, but new Portfolio backlogs can only be added as the top level, that means the hierarchy should be  `Deliverable  > Epic > Feature > Backlog Item`. So you can rename them to match your requirements, for example  rename `Feature to Deliverable`,   `Epic  to Feature`, `Deliverable  to Epic`... See the updated answer.